# How to get an id from url in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

So I have an url like this: localhost:8000/answer/create?id=254.

The full way to get is: localhost:8000/questions -> localhost:8000/questions/{question_id} -> localhost:8000/answer/create?id=254.

How to make an app read this id=254 as a question_id?

Part of Controller:

```
    /**
     * Create action.
     *
     * @param \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request          HTTP request
     * @param \App\Repository\AnswerRepository          $answerRepository Answer repository
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response HTTP response
     *
     * @throws \Doctrine\ORM\ORMException
     * @throws \Doctrine\ORM\OptimisticLockException
     *
     * @Route(
     *     "/create",
     *     methods={"GET", "POST"},
     *     name="answer_create",
     * )
     */
    public function create(Request $request, AnswerRepository $answerRepository): Response
    {
        $answer = new Answer();
        $form = $this->createForm(AnswerType::class, $answer);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $answerRepository->save($answer);
            $this->addFlash('success', 'answer_created_successfully');

            return $this->redirectToRoute('answer_index');
        }

        return $this->render(
            'answer/create.html.twig',
            ['form' => $form->createView(),
                'question_id' => $answer, ]
        );
    }
```

And template with form:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}
    {{ 'title_answer_create'|trans ({'%id%': answer.id|default('')})}}
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>{{ 'title_answer_create'|trans }}</h1>
    {{ form_start(form, { method: 'POST', action: url('answer_create') }) }}
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
    <div class="form-group row float-sm-right">
        <input type="submit" value="{{ 'action_save'|trans }}" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row float-sm-left">
        <a href="{{ url('question_index') }}" class="btn btn-link">
            {{ 'action_back_to_list'|trans }}
        </a>
    </div>
    {{ form_end(form) }}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why dont you use it like this?

```
/**
 * Create action.
 *
 * @param \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request            HTTP request
 * @param \App\Repository\AnswerRepository          $answerRepository   Answer repository
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response HTTP response
 *
 * @throws \Doctrine\ORM\ORMException
 * @throws \Doctrine\ORM\OptimisticLockException
 * @Route(
 *     "/create/{id}",
 *     methods={"GET", "POST"},
 *     name="answer_create",
 * )
 * @Entity("question", expr="repository.find(id)")
 */
public function create(Question $question, Request $request, AnswerRepository $answerRepository): Response
{


    $answer = new Answer();
    $answer->setQuestion($question);

    $form = $this->createForm(AnswerType::class, $answer);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $answerRepository->save($answer);
        $this->addFlash('success', 'answer_created_successfully');

        return $this->redirectToRoute('answer_index');
    }

    return $this->render(
        'answer/create.html.twig',
        ['form' => $form->createView(),
            'question_id' => $answer, ]
```

if possible - you should name the parameter `question_id` to make it clear what it is.

Answer (score -2):

Check the [Documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/introduction/http_fundamentals.html#symfony-request-object) as to what version of symfony you are using, but you can access query parameters via the `$request` object in your controller.

```
$question_id = $request->query->get('id');
```

Comment: `->query` is not needed.